# When there is no file uploaded using angular-file-upload directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload and I want to check when there is no file uploaded, like this:

```
<p ng-show="!uploader.queue">empty</p>
```

but `uploader.queue` is an array, and `!uploader.queue[]` doesn't work. What's the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll bite.

```
<p ng-show="!uploader.queue.length">empty</p>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length